# Firebase deploy error - node_modules missing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I've been looking fo the exact same question but i couldnt find it. Could someone tell me what is wrong with this?

[Firebase deploy error command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2pk2.jpg)

Comment: Please don't show pictures of error messages.  It's better to copy the message into the text of the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: Also, you're not showing the entire output.  There are missing warnings from eslint that are describing the problem.

Comment: where can i find the eslint though? I'm sorry but I'm a beginner in this and im trying to create a notification that can be sent through a device to another.

Comment: Copy the entire output of the deployment into the question and format it as code.

Comment: Actually, you should probably outline all the steps, starting from a new project, on how you got to this point.  You might have simply missed a step. The error message alone isn't really enough.

Comment: found the solution. I didn't log in my firebase through the command. Well that was very careless.

Comment: if this happens due to the use of yarn2 have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67424850/2477619

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

firstly i ran `sudo npm install npm -g`

secondly `npm install` in the functions folder