# How to turn off yarn@2 PnP?

Tags: yarnpkg

I am using Yarn `2.0.0-rc.27` + workspaces + TypeScript and I want to turn PnP off and use `node_modules` again. I tried it with following setting in `package.json`:

```json
"installConfig": {
  "pnp": false
},
```

However, Yarn uses PnP mode every time. Is there any option to turn it off?

Comment: if this needs to be turned of due to a firebase deploy, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67424850/2477619

Comment: It's 2023 and pnp still doesn't play nice with TypeScript.

Comment: It's horrendous, ppl shout it like a big advantage yet it breaks EVERYTHING. pnpm, bun, now yarn, only viable option is always npm..

Answer (score 118, accepted):

I ran into a bunch of issues with Yarn 2 as well using the same stack. The solution is to create a `.yarnrc.yml` file with the following line:

```yaml
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

This can also be done with following `yarn` command:

```
yarn config set nodeLinker node-modules
```

Comment: `yarn config set nodeLinker node-modules`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is enough to run `yarn unplug [problem package name]` to get it working again with pnp mode.

For instance in case of next.js v12 pnp mode started to not work again (it worked with v10/v11) and the solution was to simply `yarn unplug next` -- it  remembers that you did it by adding a new `dependenciesMeta` entry into the package.json file.