# Deploying to Firebase Functions with a monorepo

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, yarn-workspaces

As per [Firebase Functions with Yarn workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55783984/373406), I'd like to deploy a monorepo to Firebase using Yarn Workspaces. I can successfully deploy the "web" aspect to Firebase Hosting, which references a shared "core" workspace. However, attempts to do the same with the "functions" workspace on Firebase Functions fails.

I'm using Yarn Workspaces with the following folder structure:

```
packages/           
  core/             // name: firebase-monorepo-core: custom core package
  functions/        // name: firebase-monorepo-functions: firebase functions package
  web/              // name: firebase-monorepo-web: react package
```

These have been configured in the root `package.json` file:

```
"workspaces": {
    "packages": [
        "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
        "**/firebase-monorepo-core"
    ]
}
```

In an attempt to enable Yarn workspaces in Firebase (and therefore share my `core` package) I've used the `nohoist` feature to create symlinks to the `core` workspace in `functions` and `web` as per [twiz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1316229/twiz)'s [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59593707/373406).

The `core` package also exists as a dependency in `functions` and `web`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-monorepo-core": "*"
}
```

There are no problems when any of this runs locally, and in fact deployment of the `web` package to Firebase hosting works fine. However, deployment of the `functions` package to Firebase functions throws an error:

[image: Firebase functions deployment error]

I've created a Github repository https://github.com/cjmyles/firebase-monorepo to demonstrate this, and the resultant `web` workspace can be viewed at https://fir-monorepo.firebaseapp.com.

I can get the `functions` package to deploy if I `yarn pack` the `core` workspace and reference it as a tarball in the `package.json` file, but I really don't like that solution and it will require more overhead to automate it.

Any advice would be appreciated to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Would also like to know how/if you solved it

Answer (score 3):

The [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/653) is that `firebase-tools` assumes that all packages used by your function are available in npm.

A quick solution is to use firelink.

```sh
cd ./packages/functions
yarn add -D @rxdi/firelink
```

Add an equivalent section to your functions package.json for all shared dependencies.

```
  "fireDependencies": {
    "@org/common": "../../packages/common"
  },
```

Change your deploy script to use firelink binary

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build tsconfig.build.json",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",
    "deploy:functions": "firelink deploy --only functions"
  }
```

Just a heads up does not work with "devDependencies", but you should not be needing them in production anyway.

Update your firebase.json to run the predeploy target.

```json
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": ["npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run predeploy"],
    "source": "packages/functions"
  },
```

Lastly remove any local `yarn.lock` files in the workspace package. If you wish to lock the dependencies add `npm install` to your predeploy step. If anyone has a better solution to this let me know. It seem unfortunate that `yarn` does not have the ability to generate lock files on demand in a workspace.

Answer (score 2):

one potential solution is to use Lerna.

You can then publish your `core` package to a private GitHub package and use Lerna to create a symlink to the `core` package for local development.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work but it was a pain and hacky. So far it's working well though. I'm using NPM Workspaces, but the concept should apply to any project where node modules are hoisted to the root folder. I'm also using GitHub Workflows / Actions for CI and TypeScript, so all of this works within those environments.

- Build my dependent packages using TypeScript's `tsc`
- Copy the compiled files into the functions folder (`functions/src/domain` to be exact) so that they get uploaded by Firebase CLI

```
cp -r packages/domain firebase/functions/src/domain
```

- Insert local dependency inside functions/package.json. I'm doing it with `sed`, which GitHub actions supports:

```
sed -i 's/"dependencies": {/"dependencies": { "@mycompany\/domain": "file:src\/domain",/' package.json
```

Before that command, my package.json looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
  ...
```

After that command, it looks like this:

```
  "dependencies": { "@mycompany/domain": "file:src/domain",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
  ...
```

- Then deploy: `firebase deploy --only functions`

Not pretty, but it works with full automation.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a solution and wrote an article about this, but it seems that only links are not appreciated here so I'll post an excerpt. Here is the [full article](https://thijs-koerselman.medium.com/deploy-to-firebase-without-the-hacks-e685de39025e)

> ### The problem with Firebase
>
> When deploying to Firebase it wants to upload a folder just like a
> traditional single package repository, containing the source files
> together with a manifest file declaring its external dependencies.
> After receiving the files in its cloud deployment pipeline, it then
> detects the package manager and runs an install and build.
>
> In a monorepo, and especially a private one, your Firebase code
> typically depend on one or more shared packages from the same
> repository, for which you have no desire to publish them anywhere.
>
> Once Firebase tries to look up those dependencies in the cloud they
> can not be found and deployment fails.
>
> ### Hacking your way out
>
> #### Using a bundler
>
> In order to solve this you could try to use a bundler like Webpack to
> combine your Firebase code with the shared packages code and then
> remove those packages from the package.json manifest that is being
> sent to Firebase, so it doesn’t know these packages even existed.
>
> Unfortunately, this strategy quickly becomes problematic…
>
> If the shared packages themselves do not bundle all of their
> dependencies in their output, Firebase doesn’t know what the shared
> code depends on, because you are not including or installing those
> manifests.
>
> You could try to bundle everything then, but if your shared package
> depends on things your Firebase package also depends on, you now have
> one part of your code running an internally bundled copy of a
> dependency and the other part using that same dependency from a
> different location installed by the package manager.
>
> Also, some libraries really don’t like to be bundled, and in my
> experience that includes the Firebase and Google client libraries. You
> will quickly find yourself trying to externalize things via the
> bundler settings in order get thing to work.
>
> And even if you managed to make all this work, you are probably
> creating large bundles which could then lead to problems with the
> cold-start times of your cloud functions.
>
> Not exactly a reliable or scalable solution.
>
> #### Packing and linking local dependencies
>
> An arguably more elegant approach involves packing the local
> dependencies into a tarball (similar to how a package would be
> published to NPM), and copying the results to the build output before
> linking them in an altered manifest file.
>
> This could work quite nicely, as it basically resembles how your
> Firebase code would have worked if these packages were installed from
> an external domain.
>
> Whether you’re doing this manually, or write a shell script to handle
> things, it still feels very cumbersome and fragile to me, but I think
> it is a viable workaround if your local dependencies are simple.
>
> However, this approach quickly becomes hairy once you have shared
> packages depending on other shared packages, because then you’ll have
> have multiple levels of things to pack and adapt.
>
> ### My solution
>
> I have created
> [isolate-package](https://github.com/0x80/isolate-package). The name
> is generic because it doesn’t contain anything specific to Firebase,
> although I currently don’t know of any other use-cases for isolated
> output.
>
> It takes a similar approach to what is described earlier in packing
> and linking dependencies, but does so in a more sophisticated way. It
> is designed to handle different setups and package managers and it
> completely hides the complexity from the user.
>
> The isolate binary it exposes can simply be added to the Firebase
> predeploy hook, and that’s pretty much it!
>
> This also allows you to deploy to Firebase from multiple different
> packages and keep the configuration co-located instead of littering
> the monorepo root directory.
>
> It should be zero-config for the vast majority of use-cases, and is
> designed to be compatible with all package managers.