# Share types between Firebase Hosting and Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase

I have a folder structure like below. I'm trying to share `types.ts` between firebase functions and firebase hosting, stored respectively in `functions/src/` and `src/`.

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
functions/
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- src/
--- index.ts
src/
- types.ts
```

My build process is to run `npm run-script build` and then `firebase deploy` from the main project directory. This has been working for a while, but with seemingly no changes I'm now receiving the below error when I try to deploy firebase functions.

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../src/types' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I have a vague understanding that the folder structure is being lost after `tsc` does its thing. I could just duplicate the types in both spots, but this doesn't seem ideal. How can I share `types.ts` between hosting and functions?

Comment: Create a monorepo and use firelink https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322368/16967562