# (Monorepo) Firebase Functions with Shared Local Node Module across multiple Codebases: Deployment Issue

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm restructuring our Firebase Functions to better isolate different functions from one another, utilizing the codebase feature provided by Firebase. This feature allows specifying separate directories inside the main functions directory, with each having its own package.json and related files.

I've set up a shared module containing functions, constants, and types that need to be accessible across multiple codebases. Based on the [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/handle-dependencies?lang=nodejs) about handling dependencies, I've organized my directories as follows:

```
firebase-root/
|-- functions/
|   |-- shared/             # Shared node module
|   |-- codebaseA/
|   |   `-- package.json    # 'shared' dependency: file:"../shared"
|   `-- codebaseB/
|       `-- package.json    # 'shared' dependency: file:"../shared"
```

This structure works flawlessly for local development. I've used relative paths in the package.json files to reference the 'shared' module.

However, I encounter problems when deploying the codebases. Although Firebase's documentation advises placing the shared module within the functions root and outside the node_modules, the deployment process can't resolve the shared folder. My hypothesis is that during deployment, everything outside a specific codebase directory is disregarded due to the isolation principle.

To address this, I've considered using predeploy and postdeploy scripts in firebase.json:

```
      "predeploy": [
        "sed -i \"\" \"s|file:../shared|file:shared|\" functions/codebaseA/package.json",
        "cp -r shared functions/codebaseA/shared"
      ],
      "postdeploy": [
        "rm -rf functions/codebaseA/shared",
        "sed -i \"\" \"s|file:shared|file:../shared|\" functions/codebaseA/package.json"
      ]
```

These scripts essentially copy the shared directory into the codebase before deployment and adjust the package.json dependency path. This approach, albeit functional, feels quite hacky.

Is there a more elegant or recommended solution to this challenge?

I've come across this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65322368/14810569) talking about firelink, but im not sure if this would work for my case.

Comment: Running into the same issue this morning after refactored some .ts files that we share with client side (like some local StringLibs). I will now try to see if soft linking would work.

Comment: And soft-linking the lib back into the functions dir where I was working did let me deploy.

Comment: @ManabuTokunaga Thanks for your response! Symlinking the shared directory works well :)